# How to format order import styles css module to first line in eslint-plugin-import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am trying to config ESLint for my project that using `eslint-plugin-import` to ogranize module import order but I have a case with style css module. I want to place style css module import to the first line. How I can config to get my expected?
Here is my lint config for that:

.eslintrc.json

```
    "import/order": [
        "warn",
        {
            "groups": ["builtin", "object", "external", "internal", "type", "parent", "sibling", "index"],
            "pathGroups": [
                {
                    "pattern": "~/**",
                    "group": "internal",
                    "position": "after"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "**/*.{css,scss}",
                    // How I can config here?
                },
            ],
            "newlines-between": "always"
        }
    ]
```

My expected:

```
import '../styles/style.css'; 

import React from 'react';

import * as utils from '../utils'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure ESLint to place style CSS module imports at the top, you can adjust your ESLint configuration as follows:

```
"import/order": [
    "warn",
    {
        "groups": [["builtin", "external"], "internal", ["parent", "sibling", "index"]],
        "pathGroups": [
            {
                "pattern": "~/**",
                "group": "internal",
                "position": "after"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "**/*.{css,scss}",
                "group": "external",
                "position": "before"
            }
        ],
        "newlines-between": "always"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the mean of `[["builtin", "external"]` ? Is this similar to `["builtin", "external", ...]` ?

Comment: In ESLint's import/order configuration:
["builtin", "external"] creates two separate groups for "builtin" and "external" imports, defining a specific order for them.
[["builtin", "external"]] combines "builtin" and "external" imports into a single group, allowing them to appear in any order within that group.